# Why does the paraxial approximation work?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, calculus, approximations

[Paraxial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraxial_approximation) is a small angle approximation (about 5 degrees), where we study the light rays only near the center of curvature of the spherical mirror/lens. If the rays near the center are only studied, then why are the results we obtain so accurate? Why does this approximation work so perfectly if it only considers a little fraction of the light rays actually hitting the mirror/lens?

Comment: 1 radian is not a small angle.

Answer (score 0):

The paraxial approximation is a conditions that needs to be satisfied by the beam of light to which it is applied. It is better to think of it in terms of physical optics (of Fourier optics) rather than ray optics. Any beam of light can be expressed as an expansion of plane waves, leading to the notion of an *angular spectrum*. The divergence angle of the beam is related to the width of the angular spectrum. If this width is much smaller than the wavenumber $k=2\pi/\lambda$  then the beam satisfies the condition for the paraxial approximation.